# Implementing the observer pattern with nested elements

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

**Update:** So I'm still struggling to create a hierarchy where the parent is responsible for rendering its nested children, *and* keeping track of children that need to be registered/unregistered.

Basically: If I don't have a reference to the direct descendents in each view, I can't check if they are already observers in the model when they are re-created and rendered on update.

I'm starting to think I should ditch this pattern and just create a custom event, and add a listener to each document fragment as it's created (if that's even possible). At least then I can attach/remove the listener on re-render

---

Original question:

I'm trying to implement the observer pattern in JS without a controller, IE: the Model just re-renders the relevant views when its data changes.

My problem is that I need to pass a `view` to the `model`'s `registerObserver` function as a reference, else I've no way to check that the observer hasn't already been registered, here:

```
if (!this.observers.includes(observer)) 
  this.observers.push(observer)
```

If I can't check the observers they're continually added on every re-render, so I keep a reference to them in the `nestedViews` property. But I'm struggling with the problem that a parent view could also need to observe the model - so I add a reference to `self`. However if I re-render the parent view when the model changes I lose the references to the nested views, and the same problem occurs.

Relative to this approach I'm very new to webdev (this is just an exercise to improve my vanilla js), so I'm sure this must be an easy fix that I just can't see?

Parent view:

```
class View {
   nestedViews = {};
   self = this;

   constructor(parentEl, model){
     this.model = model;
     this.parentEl = parentEl;
   }

   update() { this.render(); }

   render() {
     // method to render child classes
     this.onRender();
     // bind model
     this.bindModel();
    
     //... Logic to insert the item into the dom
   }
}
```

```
class NestedView extends View {
   bindModel() {
    Object.entries(this.nestedViews).forEach(([key, value]) =>
      this.model.registerObserver(value)
    );
   }
   onRender() {
    this.nestedViews['nestedView1'] = new NestedView1(
      parent,
      this.model
    );
    this.nestedViews['nestedView1'].render();
    
    this.nestedViews['nestedView2'] = new NestedView2(
      parent,
      this.model
    );
    this.nestedViews['nestedView2'].render();
   }}
```

Model:

```
class Model {
   observers = [];

   registerObserver(observer) {

   if (!this.observers.includes(observer)) this.observers.push(observer);
  }
  unregisterObserver(observer){
    this.observers = this.observers.filter((obs) => obs !== observer);
  }
  updateObservers() {
    this.observers.forEach((observer) => observer.update());
  }

  set() {
    // set attr
    this.updateObservers();
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not long ago, I wrote a [blog](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/mastering-javascript-behavioral-design-patterns-697c4263a940) about the Observer Pattern, which may come in handy.

Comment: Will have to read again, but not entirely sure that fixes my issue with nesting, thanks though. ngl, I'm thinking of trying to use custom events instead

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the issue you're facing. You want to avoid re-rendering the parent view every time the model changes, as it causes the loss of references to the nested views. One solution would be to have a separate method to update the nested views, and call it from the parent view's update method. This way, the parent view is only responsible for updating the nested views, not re-rendering them.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
class View {
  nestedViews = {};

  constructor(parentEl, model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.parentEl = parentEl;
  }

  update() {
    // Update nested views without re-rendering the parent view
    this.updateNestedViews();
  }

  updateNestedViews() {
    Object.values(this.nestedViews).forEach((nestedView) => nestedView.update());
  }

  render() {
    // method to render child classes
    this.onRender();
    // bind model
    this.bindModel();
  }
}

class NestedView extends View {
  bindModel() {
    Object.values(this.nestedViews).forEach((nestedView) =>
      this.model.registerObserver(nestedView)
    );
  }

  onRender() {
    this.nestedViews['nestedView1'] = new NestedView1(this.parentEl, this.model);
    this.nestedViews['nestedView1'].render();

    this.nestedViews['nestedView2'] = new NestedView2(this.parentEl, this.model);
    this.nestedViews['nestedView2'].render();
  }
}
```

In this solution, the parent view's update method doesn't re-render itself; instead, it calls updateNestedViews, which in turn calls the update method on each nested view. This should help maintain the references to the nested views and prevent them from being registered as observers multiple times.

Additionally, consider using the following modified registerObserver method in your Model class to automatically unregister observers when they are destroyed or no longer needed:

```
class Model {
  // ...

  registerObserver(observer) {
    if (!this.observers.includes(observer)) {
      this.observers.push(observer);

      // Automatically unregister the observer when it's destroyed
      const unregister = () => {
        this.unregisterObserver(observer);
      };
      observer.onDestroy(unregister);
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

And in your View class, add the onDestroy method:

```
class View {
  // ...

  onDestroy(callback) {
    this._onDestroyCallback = callback;
  }

  destroy() {
    if (this._onDestroyCallback) {
      this._onDestroyCallback();
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

This way, you can call the destroy method on a view when it is no longer needed, and it will automatically unregister itself as an observer from the model.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I've got myself a little confused - I think I can prevent the parent from re-rendering by not binding it (which I think is the case in the example if you look at the bind method - I'm only refering to the nested views). But lets say somewhere in the hierarchy of elements a grandparent *and* a distant child need to re-render when the model changes - ie I'm binding both to the same model. With my technique I lose the references needed to pass to the registerObserver method. I think I'm just approaching it wrong. Thanks for that destroy method - not seen that before!